# Generating Positive Kinetic Energy (PKE) from car velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, data-analysis

PKE have high importance on fuel consummation and Eco-driving.
I have a data frame with 3 columns, Time (each second), Speed(KM/H) in each second, and RPM ,from this data frame I want to calculate positive kinetic energy.

```
Time    Engine RPM [RPM]    Vehicle Speed Sensor [km/h]     Air Flow Rate from Mass Flow Sensor [g/s]
0   2020-06-01 06:58:41.245     0.0     0.0     0.88
1   2020-06-01 06:58:42.026     0.0     0.0     0.88
2   2020-06-01 06:58:43.045     0.0     0.0     0.88
3   2020-06-01 06:58:44.035     180.0   0.0     12.02
4   2020-06-01 06:58:45.085     1010.0  0.0     16.91
```

This formula i found in this research : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235721432_Quality_assurance_of_exhaust_emissions_test_data

i didn't understand it , and why they are using PKE = sum (pow(Vf,2) - pow(Vi,2)) / distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinetic energy of an object is $K=(1/2)mv^2$. The PKE seems to be defined in the paper to be the sum of differences of squared speeds, divided by distance travelled: $$\text{PKE}=\frac{\sum_{t=0} [v(t+1)^2-v(t)^2]}{d}.$$ This is something different from normal kinetic energy.

It is worth noting that the sum above telescopes; all but the first and last terms disappear: $\text{PKE}=(v_{final}^2-v_{initial}^2)/d$. The paper also only cares about positive changes in speed. The increase in kinetic energy would then correspond to $K=(1/2)m d \text{PKE}$.

Comment: so , what i need to do in my case is to loop through that data frame, calculate the
(speed (1) )2 - (speed(0))2 and divide by the distance traveled which is speed / 3600 
(since evey row is a second ) so the distance here is in m/s right ?
and what about (speed (1) )2 - (speed(0))2 , in which unit , and finally in my case PKE is in which unit?